# Eslint configuration for express.js/mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Can some one share with me good Eslint configuration for express/mongo API implementation?

Do not satisfied with first 10 google's articles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has [ESLint](https://eslint.org/), [eslint-plugin-node](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node) (Additional ESLint's rules for Node.js),[eslint-plugin-security](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security) (ESLint rules for Node Security) integrated.
You can also integrate [prettier](https://prettier.io/).
Airbnb style guide is chosen as it's the most popular.

```
  {
  "env": {
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "plugin:node/recommended",
    "plugin:security/recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
  },
  "rules": {
    "node/exports-style": ["error", "module.exports"],
    "node/file-extension-in-import": ["error", "always"],
    "node/prefer-global/buffer": ["error", "always"],
    "node/prefer-global/console": ["error", "always"],
    "node/prefer-global/process": ["error", "always"],
    "node/prefer-global/url-search-params": ["error", "always"],
    "node/prefer-global/url": ["error", "always"],
    "node/prefer-promises/dns": "error",
    "node/prefer-promises/fs": "error"
  }
}
```